# Can't find initrd file on GRUB console

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, uefi, initrd

My PC boots to the grub command line.

```
$ ls
(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt6)  (hd1,gpt5)  (hd1,gpt4)  (hd1,gpt3)  (hd1,gpt2)  (hd1,gpt1)
(lvm/fedora-swap)  (lvm/fedora-home)  (lvm/fedora-root)

$ ls (hd1,gpt5)/
./ ../ lost+found/ efi/ extlinux/ grub2/ vmlinuz-4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64
vmlinuz-4.10.10-200.fc25.x86_64 System.map-4.10.10-200.fc25.x86_64
config-4.10.10-200.fc25.x86_64 elf-memtest86+-5.0
System.map-4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64 memtest86+-5.01
config-4.10.10-200.fc25.x86_64 .vmlinuz-4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64.hmac
initramfs-4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64.img vmlinuz-4.10.13-200.fc25.x86_64
System.map-4.10.13-200.fc25.x86_64 config-4.10.13-200.fc25.x86_64 
.vmlinuz-4.10.13-200.fc25.x86_64.hmac
  initramfs-4.13.12-200.fc25.x86_64.img .vmlinuz-4.10.10-200.fc25.x86_64.hmac
initramfs-4.10.10-200.fc25.x86_64.img
```

I've tried:

```
$ set root=(lvm/fedora-root)
$ linuxefi (hd1,gpt5)/vmlinuz-4.10.13-200.fc25.x86_64 root=/dev/sda5
$ initrd initramfs-4.13.12-200.fc25.x86_64.img
$ boot
```

After this, I get:

> [FAILED] Failed to start Switch Root.
>   See 'systemctl status initrd-switch-root.service' for detailes.
>
> Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
>
> Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
>   Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
>   You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also able to reproduce "Failed to start Switch Root" with kernel vmlinuz-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 using the following commands.

```
grub> linux /vmlinuz-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /initramfs-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64.img
grub> boot
```

At the GRUB splash screen, when I press e to edit, the following is displayed on my system.

```
linux16 /vmlinuz-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root rord.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb LANG=en_US.UTF-8
initrd16 /initramfs-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64.img
```

I made note of these parameters, and then press c again to return to the GRUB command line. I adjusted the commands to be similar to what was listed at the edit screen.

```
grub> linux16 /vmlinuz-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root rord.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb LANG=en_US.UTF-8
grub> initrd16 /initramfs-4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64.img
grub> boot
```

During boot, "Failed to start Switch Root" was no longer displayed. Does this work for you as well?